# dotnet build silently fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I run `dotnet build` it silently fails.

```
PS C:\my\dir> dotnet -d build
Telemetry is: Enabled
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29

I can see `.sln` and `.proj` files in that directory. Note, this exact same project builds fine on another machine.

Any suggestions?